# React input type number onChange is slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to set an input that users can type only numbers and one dot(ex number.number(8 digits)) using regex.

```
// component A

<Input
    name="password"
    value={this.props.password}
    onChange={this.props.onChange}
/>
```

.

```
// component B

state = { password : '' }

handleChange = (e) => {
   const value = e.target.value;
   const regexAllowOneDot = /\d+(\.?\d{0,8})/;

   if(regexAllowOneDot.exec(value) !== null) {
        this.setState({
            password: regexAllowOneDot.exec(value)[0]
        })
    }else {
        this.setState({
            password: ''
        })
   }
}


<ComponentA
   password={this.state.password}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

.

It works when type of the input is "text" but it doesn't work when the type is "number".

so, When the type is "number", I get these issues below(However, theses are totally solved when the type is "text")

1. When I check the developer tool from Chrome, the value of the input does not change (but e.target.value works)
2. Also, when I check through `console.log(regexAllowOneDot.exec(value)[0])`, It says null even though the value still has the one digit(length, like 1 or 2 or...)

I wonder why and how I can fix this or if you have a better solution.

Comment: Your handleChange function doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Oops, sorry I just edited! my original code is fine, just here i forgot to put the argument. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it now. You want to handle the keyPress event and stop it if necessary, like so:

```
keyPress = e => {
  if (e.which === 46 && this.state.amount.includes(".")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
};
```

Then pass the function down to the child component and attach it to onKeyPress.

I have included a working fork of your code with the problem solved here: https://codesandbox.io/s/7wnz19156x?codemirror=1&fontsize=14

Comment: Actually I think I might be wrong. Let me put together a snippet.

Comment: `e.target.value` is a `string` for `<input type = number />`

Comment: yeah I realized I was wrong after I said it, I moved his code into a snippet so I can figure out what is going on. My bad OP.

Comment: @JSager here's a sample code, you can test by adding/removing `type="number` in the componentA and typing "1.11...11..1" something like this.

Comment: ok I definitely see the issue. I'm working on a solution. Thanks for the sandbox.

Comment: @MijeongWon I have updated my answer to reflect the correct solution.

Comment: @JSager thanks! but I still can type multiple dots like "1.......". :'(

Comment: also, I don't understand why the value attribute doesn't show anything on the chrome developer tool when the type of input is "number". It works fine when its "text". I think the solution might be related to this. but dunno exactly how to :'(

Comment: I am surprised that you are still seeing multiple dots, because that's explicitly what I checked for in my solution, and I am also running chrome. When you get a second dot, the value will be "" because it's invalid. This should have prevented that. Why don't you send me a chat and I'll work with you on it.

Comment: @MijeongWon ok I found the case where you could still press two dots. I am updating the sandbox link with a new solution. I had to track the prior key press in component state.